# Picture rotation c++

Tags: c++

I have a project where it is needed to rotate an image around its xy coordinates given the factor z.
We are allowed to use opencv for getting the picture assigned to a Mat object only but the rest we'll have to do only using C++

It was easy enough to do the task with open CV(import image) but I'm kind of lost on the rest of the assignment... Please give me som help.

I guess I'll have to move the matrices around in order to rotate the picture around, but every time I have tried to do that it just change the matrices instead of moving them.

Comment: I suppose you need: load image, assign transformation matrix, output the image (during this process matrix actually applies) - result is rotated image

Answer (score 0):

Try the articles found at:

- http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/article.php/c3693/Rotate-a-Bitmap-at-Any-Angle-Without-GetPixelSetPixel.htm
- http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/specialeffects/article.php/c1743/Rotate-a-bitmap-image.htm

and also a little more googleing might help.